# How to mimic Thick Stylish Font used in the cover page of the book : Problems in General Physics by I. E. Irodov

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am trying to mimic the thick stylish font used in cover page of the book : 
[image: Problems in General Physics by I. E. Irodov]

MWE is :

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, svgnames]{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-text, pagecolor, xcolor}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{3.8cm}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{Black}
\color{White}

\rput(2.7in,.0in){\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!50]{\RM Problems}}
\rput(3in,-1.2in){\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!50]{\RM in General}}
\rput(2.15in,-2.5in){\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!50]{\RM Physics}}

\end{document}
```

This produces : [image: Cover Title]

But this is pretty far from the original.

Any ideas ??

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Please don't use `minimal` for examples. It is absolutely not designed for them.

Comment: See the LaTeX Font Catalogue if you want a traditional TeX font. You've tagged this `xetex`, though, so you can use any opentype or truetype font available to you. You've also tagged it `tikz-pgf` and `pstricks`. Why??

Comment: If you are using XeTeX, you should almost certainly not declare a font like that. You should use `fontspec`.

Comment: 70's font... groovy...

Answer (score 4):

I uploaded your image to https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator which suggested cooper black which seems to be available on this windows box so..

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{COOPBL.TTF}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont

\centering

Problems\\
in General\\
Physics

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, although I'm using `pdflatex`, and it seems that `\usepackage{fontspec}` is not available. Anyone know an alternative that works for `pdflatex`?